# search based on the option of the select menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I'm new to JS an React. I have a table which contains phone numbers of a group of people. Here is a piece of my table code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

const Table = () => {

    const navigate = useNavigate()

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    const [currentUsers, setCurrentUsers] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

    useEffect(async () => {
        try {
            const response = await getUsers(search);
            setUsers(response.data.users);

        } catch (error) { }
    }, [search]);

   return (
       <input type='text' placeholder='search..' onChange={(e) => setSearch(e.target.value)} value={search} />
       <select aria-label=".form-select-sm example">
          <option selected value="1">all</option>
          <option value="2">name</option>
          <option value="3">phone</option>
       </select>
       <table className='w-full border-separate rounded-md'>
                <thead>
                    <tr className='bg-text-secondary text-white shadow-sm text-center'>
                        <th className='p-2'>name</th>
                        <th className='p-2'>phone</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {currentUsers.map((item, index) =>
                        <tr key={item.id} className={index % 2 === 0 ? 'bg-white shadow-sm text-center' : 'bg-text bg-opacity-5 shadow-sm text-center'}>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.name}</td>
                            <td className='text-text text-sm p-2'>{item.phone}</td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
   )
}
```

Here is the getUsers definition:

```
export const getUsers = async (search) => {
    const apiUrl = `${baseApiUrl}/users?search=${search}`;
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const response = await axios.get(apiUrl, {
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });
    return response.data;
};
```

As you see I have a box for search inside the table. By default, when I search for something, it searches all the columns and their values. Here is how usersList returns when I search for something and it is implemented in back-end:

```
const usersList = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { search } = req.query
    try {
        //filter users
        const users = await userModel.find({
            $or: [
                { name: { $regex: search } },
                { phone: { $regex: search } },
            ]
        })
        res.send({
            success: true,
            message: 'user list returned',
            data: {
                total_records: users.length,
                users,
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to search specific columns.

As a result, I added a select menu with three options above the table:

```
all: search all columns (default behavior)
name: select *name* column
phone: select *phone* column
```

but I cannot figure out how I can make it possible that when I select `name` option for example and write something in the search bar, only search in this column. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this sending the search type also in request and based on that search type you can give conditions.To do this:-
First add one more state in your table component.

```js
const [searchType, setSearchType] = useState("1");
```

After change change select element to

```js
<select aria-label=".form-select-sm example" value={searchType} onChange={(event) => setSearchType(event.target.value)}>
   <option selected value="1">all</option>
   <option value="2">name</option>
   <option value="3">phone</option>
</select>
```

Now in getUsers method pass serachType and after that send as queryString in url. Based on searchType get the data.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do do this, because I'm really new to JS.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you haven't implement the "search by column" in your back-end. You should send the column type along with the search keyword in your request query. And in your back-end code

```
const { search, column } = req.query;
```

Then update the $or dynamically.

```
const all = [
        { name: { $regex: search } },
        { phone: { $regex: search } },
];
const users = await userModel.find({
    $or: column != null ? all.filter((item) => Object.keys(item)[0] === column) : all,
})
```

Note: you should validate if the column value is valid in a middleware.

Comment: How can I send the column type along with the search keyword in my request query?

Comment: Create a state to keep track of your select input presumably `column`. And in getUsers function, ``const apiUrl = `${baseApiUrl}/users?search=${search}&column=${column}``;

Comment: Should I add something like `onClick={(e) => setColumn(e.target.value)} value={column}` on each option of my select menu too?

Comment: Plese read [offical docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag) for using select in react.

Comment: I applied all you had said, but I wasn't successful in editing the select menu.

Comment: Using this code, when I try to add a new user, I receive this error: `MongoServerError: $and/$or/$nor must be a nonempty array`. Although the user is added to Mongo DB, the user is not added to the table.